# Azure git how to make Python script unbuffered

Tags: python, git, azure, output, unbuffered

In an Azure git pipeline script (.yml), I can set up a Python task like this

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: "Run scripts"
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: 'myscript.py'
    arguments: '$a $b $c'
```

But it doesn't print output until the task is complete. Normally I would call `python -u myscript.py` but there isn't an option to pass parameters to python itself; they can only be passed to the script. How can I set the input as unbuffered?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself; it's specific to the Azure setup. However, they (Microsoft) copied a lot of this from others, and/or vice versa, so other pipeline setups use similar syntax in their YAML scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the Azure .yml script makes the output unbuffered, so that print statements appear right away:

```
variables:
- name: PYTHONUNBUFFERED
  value: PYTHONUNBUFFERED
```

It's an environment variable, and adding it here sets the value.